# error: (-215:Assertion failed) totalSampleCount > 0 in function 'GMM::endLearning'

Tags: opencv

Im trying to use the opencv to remove the background of my pictures.
When Im running a single file. It works out.
The code as below:

```
def bgremove(name,count):
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    # cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    #Load the Image

    imgo = cv2.imread(name)# the place to input picture path
    height,width = imgo.shape[:2]

    #Create a mask holder
    mask = np.zeros(imgo.shape[:2],np.uint8)

    #Grab Cut the object
    bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
    fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

    #Hard Coding the Rect… The object must lie within this rect.
    rect = (10,10,width-30,height-30)
    cv2.grabCut(imgo,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
    mask = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
    img1 = imgo*mask[:,:,np.newaxis]

    #Get the background
    background = imgo-img1

    #Change all pixels in the background that are not black to white
    background[np.where((background > [0,0,0]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]

    #Add the background and the image
    final = background + img1
    DP1=count

    #To be done – Smoothening the edges….
    cv2.imwrite("A%s.JPG"%DP1, final)
```

However, when I use the function in a for loop. it pops-up:

> error: (-215:Assertion failed) totalSampleCount > 0 in function
>   'GMM::endLearning'

when Im generating a group of pictures

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and the issue was that the rectangle `rect` was too small. I don't know the dimensions of your image but try a bigger rectangle and it may solve this.